# Send Data from form to Database

Tags: php, html

This select sends the variable `$fetch['name_alb']` to the database
I want to send the variable `$fetch['id']` to the database

```
    <select name='id_alb'>
    <?php
        $get ='SELECT * FROM name_alb';
        $run_get = mysqli_query($con,$get);
        while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($run_get)){
            echo'<option name="'.$fetch['id'].'">'.$fetch['name_alb'].'</option>
            ';
        }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Start by learning proper HTML `name` is a faulty `<option>` attribute.

Comment: `name=` should be `value=` in each `<option>` tag.

Comment: Change attribute of `<option>` from `name` to `value`

Comment: change `echo'<option name="'.$fetch['id'].'">'.$fetch['name_alb'].'</option>` to `echo'<option value="'.$fetch['id'].'">'.$fetch['name_alb'].'</option>` `option` does not have a name attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference please note that option element has value attribute that
is sent when submitting form. At this stage you are only using name and innerHTML, that's why form isn't sent properly

```
<select name='id_alb'>
<?php
    $get ='SELECT * FROM name_alb';
    $run_get = mysqli_query($con,$get);
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($run_get))
    {
      echo "<option value=".$fetch['id'].">".$fetch['name_alb']."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: You still have `name` attribute in your answer

Comment: Thank you, forgot to delete.